# jQuery : how to select a checked radio?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

What I'm trying to achieve here is to unhide a radio button when another radio from another set is selected. But for some reason I can't succeed to select a checked radio button with jQuery selectors. I'm trying to find a solution **based on a checked radio input selector and not based on a radio value selector.** So using $(stuff).val won't do it.
The following code is not working because of the selector $(".radio-838 .first input[type=radio]").is(":checked") which is invalid:

```js
  if ($(".radio-838 .first input[type=radio]").is(":checked")){
   $(".radio-839 .first").show();
  }
  else{
   $(".radio-839 .first").hide();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formel" id="formtde">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p>
  <span class="radio-838">
  <span class="first">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="JOHN">
    <span>JOHN</span>
   </label>
  </span>
  <span class="last">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="BOBBY">
    <span>BOBBY</span>
   </label>
  </span>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>

<div class="formel" id="formgec">
 <h3>Car</h3>
 <p>
 <span class="radio-839">
   <span class="first">
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="FORD">
     <span>FORD</span>
    </label>
   </span>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="CHEVROLET">
     <span>CHEVROLET</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="PORSCHE">
     <span>PORSCHE</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="NISSAN">
     <span>NISSAN</span>
    </label>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

I also tried
$(".radio-838 .first input:radio]").is(":checked")

Comment: You want to show last radio button if first radio button is clicked right?

Comment: Yes sorry I wasn't clear at all about that: I would like to unhide FORD when JOHN is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var checkInput = function(e){
  var target = e.target || $('.radio-838');
  $(".radio-839 .first")[
     $(target).closest('.radio-838').find('.first input').is(':checked') ?
     'show':'hide'
  ]();
};

$('.radio-838').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', checkInput);
$(window).on('load', checkInput);
```

```js
var checkInput = function(e){
  var target = e.target || $('.radio-838');
  $(".radio-839 .first")[$(target).closest('.radio-838').find('.first input').is(':checked') ? 'show':'hide']();
};

$('.radio-838').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', checkInput);
$(window).on('load', checkInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formel" id="formtde">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p>
  <span class="radio-838">
  <span class="first">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="JOHN">
    <span>JOHN</span>
   </label>
  </span>
  <span class="last">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="BOBBY">
    <span>BOBBY</span>
   </label>
  </span>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>

<div class="formel" id="formgec">
 <h3>Car</h3>
 <p>
 <span class="radio-839">
   <span class="first">
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="FORD">
     <span>FORD</span>
    </label>
   </span>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="CHEVROLET">
     <span>CHEVROLET</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="PORSCHE">
     <span>PORSCHE</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="NISSAN">
     <span>NISSAN</span>
    </label>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Your main problem is your code only executes when it's loaded, not when you're making a change to the input. So here's what I did:

- made a function that would show/hide the input based on the check.
- trigger the function on window `load` event and on `.radio-838 input` `change` event.

Comment: Thanks, but how come I can't navigate through my DOM with a selector like $(".radio-838 .first input[type=radio]").is(":checked") ? Is there a less "complicated" way to achieve this?

Comment: You can, and it works. But only when the page loads. I could have used your code inside the function. I went for the `$(selector)[ condition? doTrue : doFalse ]()` syntax just to give you a glimpse on alternatives. `JavaScript` is flexible. And `jQuery` is `JavaScript` :)

Comment: I toyed with my first snippet and wrote this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqVqQp I could get FORD to display but when BOBBY is selected, FORD is still showing. Could you please help me understand why? (I'm educating myself)

Comment: @KimberleyFurson sure. The container of "Bobby" is `.last`, not `.first`. Therefore, your  `$(".radio-838 .first").on( "change" , "input:radio", function(){})` does not fire, because it's bound on `$(".radio-838 .first")`. And no `change` event happens in any element that matches that selector.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get it because I thought clicking on BOBBY, was considered as a "change" for JOHN